# Getting unhandled IOException on globally defined variable - JAVA

Tags: java, ioexception

How can one stop the IOException question being raised on something as such:

```
public class ExampleClass {

   String path = "path to directory";
   Path filePath = Paths.get(path);
   BasicFileAttributes Attr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);

   ...

}
```

I receive a warning from IntelliJ stating `Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException` on the last line `BasicFileAttributes inAttr = Files.readAttributes(filePathIn, BasicFileAttributes.class);`

If I put these declarations within a method that throws an IOException, the warning does go away... But I am wanting this declared as a global variable... Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you should read this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: negative vote? Bugger off. Was a simple enough question, just a curiosity!

Comment: I downvoted the question because it doesn't show any research effort : http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Do you want my internet search history? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can circumvent that by initializing Attr inside the constructor (wrapped in a try-catch block).

```
public ExampleClass(){
    try {
            Attr = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(""), BasicFileAttributes.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand doing something like that, or by placing in a method... Was just curious if there was any way around it.

Comment: Finding a way around it is pointless, since it would make the concept of checked and unchecked exceptions obsolete. Look at the link of Mickaël B.